# Qatar-SAS Baggage Checkin

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways, sas

I have a flight from Doha to London with Qatar Airways and then with SAS to Oslo. I just talked with Qatar helpdesk, they said that the baggage will only be checked-in till London. Both flights are on same ticket and same reference number. The transit time is just 1 hour 35 minutes and from terminal T4 to T2. This seems impossible. Is there anything I can do?